# Get different result when use i iteration and np.sum function

Tags: python-2.7, sum, iteration

I have a pandas Dataframe, I want to get the sum of the 'daily return' column of the data frame for every 60 days. The following is  my code:

```
day = days() #days is a function to count business days.
for day>60: 
    for i  in range(day-60,day): 
        current_x = sh600004['daily return'][i]
        x_list.append(current_x)
        x_sum = sum(x_list)
        print x_sum
```

Here's what I got[image]

To test the result, I used the following code:

```
y = sh600004
y.apply(lambda x: x.sum())
```

and I got different result.[image]

The sum of 'daily return' column is not the same. When I print out my dataframe sh600004, I realize the data in `x_sum` is same as sh600004['daily return'], not the sum of it.

What do I need to do to get the sum of every 60 days of the daily return ? Can anyone help, please?

I don't know is that gonna help or not, but here's my the code I wrote so far:

```
#calculate daily return
daily_close = sh600004['close']
daily_pct_c = daily_close.pct_change().fillna(0)
sh600004['daily return'] = daily_pct_c


def days():
    day = np.busday_count((datetime.datetime.strptime(sh600004['date'][0], '%Y/%m/%d')),pd.to_datetime(date), weekmask='1111100', holidays=holiday_list) 
    return day

def xn_deviation():
    x_list = []
    deviation_list = []
    z_list = []
    diff_list = []
    result_list  = []
    day = days()
    for i in range(0, 60):
        current_x = sh600004['daily return'][i]
        x_list.append(current_x)
        x_sum = sum(x_list)
        x_average = x_sum/len(x_list) #xn average
        x_deviation = current_x - x_average #xn deviation
        deviation_list.append(x_deviation)
        dev_sum = sum(deviation_list) #calculate Z
        z_list.append(dev_sum) #deviation sum list
        r = max(z_list)-min(z_list) #calculate widest deviation
        diff = np.square(current_x - x_average)
        diff_list.append(diff)
        sum_diff = sum(diff_list)
        s = np.sqrt(sum_diff/len(x_list))
        result_list = [r,s]
        return result_list
    else:
        for i  in range(day-60,day):
            #same code as before

#loop
for date in sh600004.index:
    days()
    xn_deviation()
```

Comment: Does `days()` return a constant? If so, then either you have a typo, or your code is either going to fail to execute, or else get stuck in an infinite loop, because nowhere in that block of code are you updating the value of `day`.

Comment: I add the full code, the `days()` returns a constant which varies with `date`.  I think the `#loop` of `date` should update the value of `day`.  I feel the `x_list.append(current_x)` didn't work correctly, but I don't know why. It seems it didn't add items in the `x_list`, it rather put each `current_x` in a new list.